# Elasticsearch 5.6.4 version, How to change _id value?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, elasticsearch-plugin

We are using 5.6.4 ES version and created index,type and loaded 1000+ records. Currently, we are accessing the data using (http://localhost:9200/college/dep/1 )
collect - index dep(department) - is type and  value 1 is department id.

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"id":1,"name":"maths","professors":"[a,b,c]"}
```

now we want to access with name like this http://localhost:9200/college/dep/maths. Now data is loaded already in ES . how can change _id value ? any solution.

Comment: You need to delete your existing data and reindex the documents with the other id.

Comment: @Val. another alternative solution.we have partial sources( in production 12k)..i think  re index will NOT help here

Comment: Any suggestion ..

Comment: Well, since the documents exist in your index already, you cannot just change their id, you need to reindex them and remove the ones with the bad id. That's something you need to think about *before* indexing, otherwise, there's a little price to pay.

Comment: Thanks @Val. Have any java api to read given input. API is returning some addition extra key and value. {
  "_index": "college",
  "_type": "dep",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "maths",
    "professors": "[a,b,c]"
  }
} - only _source value for all records